# Is any work being done on a .Net port of Solr?

Tags: .net, solr, lucene.net, solrnet

I'm looking to embed Solr as a library in a .Net app. I understand that there is an [embedded Java client](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/src/webapp/src/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.java) which queries a Solr core directly, and I could potentially run this on IKVM, however, I'm looking for something which has been translated. I also have looked at [Solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/), but it appears to be only a client to an http-hosted Solr instance, which I also don't want.

Is anyone aware of work on a Solr.Net conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no, nobody's working on such a port.

[I did try IKVM for this](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/SolrIKVM/) over a year ago, but it's not as easy as it might seem. Lots of errors about classes not found, and it seems that it's not always possible to pass your own ClassLoader. But you're more than welcome to pick up where I left off ;-)

UPDATE: I made [significant progress with Solr + IKVM](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/02/running-solr-on-net.html)

Comment: What are your thoughts about a straight api-to-api port, similar to Lucene.Net? The Solr codebase doesn't look overwhelming...

Comment: @codekaizen: it's over 500 classes in core Solr alone, IMHO that qualifies as a *lot* of work. And you'd be constantly playing catch-up with Java-Solr, which develops quickly. So unless you have lots of resources or a lot of time, I wouldn't go there. Even an IKVM solution would be of limited use, as everyone just uses the HTTP interface.

Comment: yes, but they are small classes. :) I think it's still small compared to Lucene and Hibernate. I'm not sure if there is no value in converting and maintaining, since not running a Java stack has a cost savings.

Comment: @codekaizen: about those cost savings: try scaling Solr on Windows... ;-)